# symfony 2.8 log viewer - where to submit?

Tags: apache, symfony, logging, viewer

i created simple symfony and apache log viewer.

https://github.com/lev-savranskiy/php-symfony-log-viewer

can not find centralized directory where symfony  developers can  submit own modules.

could you please tell me where it is?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... there's no official channel for publishing Symfony "packages".

In fact, you should to submit your [Symfony bundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles.html) or PHP package to [packagist.](https://packagist.org/) this one is far the most popular PHP packages center.

Take a look at **Publishing Packages** session in https://packagist.org in order to learn how to publish PHP packages.

Comment: thank you.


added https://packagist.org/packages/lev-savranskiy/php-symfony-log-viewer